# I'm confused about jagged arrays. I'm trying to make a for loop while accessing, print or change elements. How can I do this?

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

This is what I have so far. I'm trying to access and change the values

```
int[][] numbers = new int[][]{ //giving the values...
new int[]{4,5,6,7},
new int[]{6,88,9},
new int[]{4}
};

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
   'change value, access value or print values...'
}
```

Comment: A jagged array is an array of arrays, so `numbers[i]` gives you access to the array that `numbers` holds at position `i`. You can use that nested array just as you would any other array. For example, you can find its length by using `numbers[i].Length`.

Answer (score 3):

In Jagged Array, you can point to the array using the first index, and with the second index point to the number in each array. Try this.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[][] numbers = new int[][]{ //giving the values...
            new int[]{4,5,6,7},
            new int[]{6,88,9},
            new int[]{4}
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
           for (var j = 0; j < numbers[i].Length; j++)
           {
               Console.Write(numbers[i][j] + "\t");
           }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest way for access and print value and you can change value in item variable.

```
    foreach (var sub_arr in numbers)
    {
        foreach (var item in sub_arr)
            Console.Write(item + "\t");
        Console.WriteLine("-");
    }
```